# Animations triggered by events in SwiftUI

Tags: animation, swiftui

SwiftUI animations are typically driven by state, which is great, but sometimes you really want to trigger a temporary (often reversible) animation in response to some event. For example, I want to temporarily increase the size of a button when a it is tapped (both the increase and decrease in size should happen as a single animation when the button is released), but I haven't been able to figure this out.

It can sort of be hacked together with transitions I think, but not very nicely. Also, if I make an animation that uses autoreverse, it will increase the size, decrease it and then jump back to the increased state.

Comment: Can you use something like this? (It's from beta 1 or 2, so it may not work anymore.) https://alejandromp.com/blog/2019/06/22/swiftui-reusable-button-style/

Comment: Thank you for the interesting link, but unfortunately this suffers from the same problem as kontiki’s solution: it relies on state, in the pressed state the button has one size, in the non-pressed state it has the normal size. I would need the animation to play itself forwards and then backwards automatically when i trigger it.

Answer (score 4):

That is something I have been into as well.

So far my solution depends on applying **GeometryEffect** modifier and misusing the fact that its method **effectValue** is called continuously during some animation. So the desired effect is actually a transformation of interpolated values from 0..1 that has the main effect in 0.5 and no effect at 0 or 1

*It works great, it is applicable to all views not just buttons, no need to depend on touch events or button styles, but still sort of seems to me as a hack.*

Example with random rotation and scale effect:

[image]

Code sample:

```
struct ButtonEffect: GeometryEffect {

    var offset: Double // 0...1

    var animatableData: Double {
        get { offset }
        set { offset = newValue }
    }

    func effectValue(size: CGSize) -> ProjectionTransform {

        let effectValue = abs(sin(offset*Double.pi))
        let scaleFactor = 1+0.2*effectValue

        let affineTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(effectValue)).translatedBy(x: -size.width/2, y: -size.height/2).scaledBy(x: CGFloat(scaleFactor), y: CGFloat(scaleFactor))

        return ProjectionTransform(affineTransform)
    }
}

struct ButtonActionView: View {
    @State var animOffset: Double = 0
    var body: some View {
        Button(action:{
            withAnimation(.spring()) {
                self.animOffset += 1
            }
        })
        {
            Text("Press ME")
                .padding()
        }
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .modifier(ButtonEffect(offset: animOffset))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I will test it out. I had never heard of GeometryEffect before!

Comment: you are welcome, I have just published a short [blogpost](https://izakpavel.github.io/development/2019/08/29/tweaking-animations-with-GeometryEffect.html) about GeometryEffect, if you are interested

Comment: @PavelZak how would yo fix the issue of centering the view? let's say that you only want the view to scale. Btw, great work!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `@State` variable tied to a longPressAction():

[image]

**Code updated for Beta 5:**

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            MyButton(label: "Button 1")
            Spacer()
            MyButton(label: "Button 2")
            Spacer()
            MyButton(label: "Button 3")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct MyButton: View {
    let label: String
    @State private var pressed = false


    var body: some View {

        return Text(label)
            .font(.title)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(10)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).foregroundColor(.green))
            .scaleEffect(self.pressed ? 1.2 : 1.0)
            .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: .infinity, maximumDistance: .infinity, pressing: { pressing in
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2)) {
                    self.pressed = pressing
                }
            }, perform: { })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer my friend, this does what it says it does, but unfortunately in my case i only have a single event to trigger the scale-up and scale-down, So I don’t think I can use a pure state approach. In this example, I would need both parts of the animations to run when you release the finger!

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you're after. (this is how I solved this problem)

Based on dfd's link in i came up with this, which is not dependent on any @State variable. You simply just implement your own button style.
No need for Timers, @Binding, @State or other complex workarounds.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyCustomPressButton: ButtonStyle {  
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding(10)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.8 : 1.0)
    }
}

struct Play: View {
    var body: some View {
            Button("Tap") {
         }.buttonStyle(MyCustomPressButton())
            .animation(.easeIn(duration: 0.2))
    }
}

struct Play_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Play()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no getting around the need to update via state in SwiftUI.  You need to have some property that is only true for a short time that then toggles back.

The following animates from small to large and back.

```swift
struct ViewPlayground: View {

    @State var enlargeIt = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Event!") {
            withAnimation {
                self.enlargeIt = true
            }
        }
        .background(Momentary(doIt: self.$enlargeIt))
        .scaleEffect(self.enlargeIt ? 2.0 : 1.0)
    }
}

struct Momentary: View {
    @Binding var doIt: Bool
    var delay: TimeInterval = 0.35
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if self.doIt {
                ZStack { Spacer() }
                    .onAppear {
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + self.delay) {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.doIt = false
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately `delay` was necessary to get the animation to occur when setting `self.enlargeIt = true`.  Without that it only animates back down.  Not sure if that's a bug in Beta 4 or not.

Comment: Yeah I understand, there needs to be some state change. But I’m thinking it should be possible to trigger a more complex animation, like a scaleup followed by a scaledown, whenever the state changes.